# How can I download a file using the WebHDFS knox groovy library?

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights, biginsight-examples

The WebHDFS [examples](https://github.com/snowch/biginsight-bluemix-docs/blob/master/examples/WebHdfsGroovy/README.md) shows how to list files and folders in hdfs, make a directory and upload a file using BigInsights WebHDFS?

How can I adapt the examples to download a file for BigInsights WebHDFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The knox api [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KNOX/Examples+WebHDFS#ExamplesWebHDFS-WebHDFSviaKnoxShellDSL) provides many more examples, e.g.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.Hadoop
import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.hdfs.Hdfs

gateway = "https://localhost:8443/gateway/sample"
username = "bob"
password = "bob-password"
dataFile = "README"

session = Hadoop.login( gateway, username, password )
text = Hdfs.get( session ).from( "/tmp/example/README" ).now().string
file = new File('README') 
file << text
session.shutdown()
```